# Integer solutions of $(n+p-1)^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor-1}+p^{\varphi(n)}=m+\frac{p!}m.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find all $(p,m,n)$ such that
>   $$(n+p-1)^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor-1}+p^{\varphi(n)}=m+\frac{p!}m,$$
>   where $m,n\in\Bbb N$, $p$ prime and $m^2<p<(m+1)^2$, $\varphi$ is the Euler-phi function.

Using the fact that $\varphi(n)\ge\sqrt n$ and $p>\varphi(n)$, we get the lower bound $n<p^2$.

When $p<10^4$, the only solutions are $(2,1,1),(2,1,2)$ and $(7,2,5)$. Are there any solutions for $p>10^4$? If no, can we prove it?